# Qt 5.7 -> 5.8 add QIcon to QListwidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.7, qt5.8, qicon

I want to upgrade my project from Qt 5.7 to Qt5.8. I have a function which shows an image on a `QListWidget`.

My project, a viewer makes a thumbnail from image and convert it to a `QIcon`.  After creating the `QIcon` it is added to the `QListWidget` by inserting a new `QListwidgetItem`.

In 5.7 that worked well, but in 5.8 thumbnails are not shown.

Belows are codes

`QIcon` to `QListWidget`:

```
QIcon tmpIcon(pathOfImage);

ui.listWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(tmpIcon, pathOfImage));
```

What makes this happen? How can I adjust to 5.8?

---

- In 5.7 it works:

  [image: In 5.7 it works!]
- In 5.8 it doesnt:

  [image: In 5.8 ....]

---

But right now, I found that small size of PNG can be shown in 5.8.

I don't know what is the problem. Maybe the size or the format of the image?

In 5.7 that didn't affect the `QListwidget`!

Comment: looks like property `uniformItemSizes` was somehow set to `true` leading to this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it!

Comment: ui.listWidget->setUniformItemSizes(false); 
 I used above code but it didn't work TT

Comment: also it was already "false" at start to end

Answer (score 0):

I did a experiment.

```
    QListWidgetItem* newItem = new QListWidgetItem();
    newItem->setIcon(tmpIcon);
    newItem->setText(pathOfImage);
```

after this, I tried to get newItem(QListWIdgetItem)'s icon and saved it to png.

```
   QIcon te2 = newItem->icon();
   QPixmap test = te2.pixmap(te2.actualSize(QSize(1024, 1024)));
   QFile file1(te + "yourFile.png");
   file1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   test.save(&file1, "PNG");
```

Regular JPG files couldn't be saved but only small logo png file could be saved properly. I think that set process between QIcon and QListWitgetItem is the main problem.